# How to fetch ETH/USD price from the coinmarketcap api

Tags: cpp-ethereum, php

I want to fetch the current ETH-USD price from this api (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=USD). How do I fetch just the price into a variable in PHP for reuse on my application?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to access the url, read the contents of the url, and then turn the contents into an object or array (in this case it'll be an array).

```
<?php

  $url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=USD';
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  $priceInfo = json_decode($data);

  echo $priceInfo[0]->price_usd;

?>
```

The **price_usd** can be changed depending on what data you want to grab. For example, this code would give you $463.531.

Comment: The coinmarket api has been migrated to new api. You need api keys now to access the api. There is a free base plan as well. You can find more details here : https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/migrate/

Answer (score 1):

Coinmarketcap is starting to charge for API. Perhaps you could have a look at CoinGecko API instead: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=ethereum

Here is the api docs: https://www.coingecko.com/api/docs/v3